# How to use regular expression to match square brackets of values and store in python dictionary?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a data and want to get the results stored in a python dictionary as below:

```
#example mydicdata[key] = values in the brackets 
#example mydicdata[0] = [""]
#example mydicdata[7] = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'... ] 

import re
data = "{0=[], 1=[], 2=[], 3=[], 4=[], 5=[], 6=[], 7=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,     7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 8=[], 9=[], 10=[], 11=[], 12=[], 13=[], 14=[], 15=[], 16=[], 17=[], 18=[], 19=[], 20=[], 21=[], 22=[], 23=[], 24=[], 25=[], 26=[], 27=[], 28=[], 29=[], 30=[], 31=[], 32=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 33=[], 34=[], 35=[], 36=[], 37=[], 38=[], 39=[], 40=[], 41=[], 42=[], 43=[], 44=[], 45=[], 46=[], 47=[], 48=[], 49=[], 50=[], 51=[], 52=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 53=[], 54=[], 55=[], 56=[], 57=[], 58=[], 59=[], 60=[], 61=[], 62=[], 63=[], 64=[], 65=[], 66=[], 67=[], 68=[], 69=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 70=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 71=[], 72=[], 73=[], 74=[], 75=[], 76=[], 77=[], 78=[], 79=[], 80=[], 81=[], 82=[], 83=[], 84=[], 85=[], 86=[], 87=[], 88=[88], 89=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 90=[], 91=[], 92=[], 93=[], 94=[], 95=[], 96=[], 97=[], 98=[], 99=[], 100=[], 101=[], 102=[], 103=[]}"
data = data[1:-1] 
temp = re.split(r'[\d=/[[0-9?,/d?/]]]',data)
```

I think I'm almost there, but the result I got here is a big chunk of list  0=[]....,103[].

Could you please give me the guideline? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a way to do it without regex: your data string is almost python (just need to replace the `=` by `:`); then `ast.literal_eval` can turn the string into a python dictionary:

```
from ast import literal_eval
data = '''{ 0=[], 1=[], 2=[], 3=[], 4=[], 5=[], 6=[], 
            7=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,     7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
           17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 
           32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
           47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
           62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
           77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
           93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 8=[], 9=[], 
           10=[], 11=[], 12=[], 13=[], 14=[], 15=[], 16=[], 17=[], 18=[]
         # more data
        }'''

dct = literal_eval(data.replace('=', ':'))
print dct[0]  # -> []
print dct[7]  # -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...,100, 101, 102, 103]
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Why I didn't think about this? That's much better. Thank you.